# jQuery delegate

Tags: jquery, delegates

i am slightly confused about how jquery's [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) Function works.

If I have a variable called picker which contains.

This variable contains a div, 
which in turn contains an unknown amount of spans.

I am looking to setup some click handlers on every single span **inside** the picker div.

Is delegate the best way to do this?

If so, How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm assuming picker looks something like this:

```
var picker = $("div.someDiv");
```

And you want to attach click handlers to all `span` elements that are child nodes of `div.someDiv` using `.delegate()`.

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
picker.delegate("span", "click", function(eventObj) {
    // do what you want
});
```

`.delegate()` works by taking advantage of the fact that most DOM events bubble, or propagate. `.delegate()` is very similar to `.live()` in this regard. Where `.delegate()` differs is that instead of just attaching your handler at the document root, and firing your handler when your event bubbles all the way up, it attaches the event to the element that you pass to `$()`, and then watches for events to bubble up from that element's children.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you should be able to do it like:

```
picker.delegate("span", "click", function() {
     // do something to $(this) here!
});
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, I have accepted Alex's Answers purly for the fact it has a description of how delegate works :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
$("#picker span").click(function(){
    //I was clicked
});
```

?